# Is the number of Web Applications SE visitors saturated?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that the visitor count for Web Applications is limited to 3k for at least a week.

Is the number of visitors starting to saturate for Web Applications?

Comment: Everybody already deleted their Facebook accounts...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

These 3k people are those who have found us via advertisements on StackOverflow, SuperUser, and ServerFault, following Jeff and Joel on Twitter, and/or who follow Area 51. As Google indexes the site and brings people here for their search queries, a lot of people will begin to use it to ask new questions.

Comment: it takes a fair bit for Google visitors to ramp up, if SU, SF, and SO are any indication.

Comment: Jeff, did/do you happen to have access to graphs showing users, with the dates of different events (such as opening to Google) that you could possibly share? I would expect similar graphs (although perhaps not as dramatic in numbers) as the first three sites in the trilogy.